# CSS - Tips for this layout strategy? Three background layers

Tags: html, css

so I've got this webdesign I'm trying to put together with CSS and I'm struggling a bit on the CSS layout of divs.

Things is, I want a main background. Then a layer on top of that with a semi-transparent png image to simulate shadow. And on top of that again, I want another semi-transparent png image, only centered. And then a header and a footer.

I was thinking something in the lines of this when it comes to DIVs:

- Wrapper (main background)

  - Shadow (layer on top of main background)

    - Header
    - Centered png as background

      - Main content
- Footer

What I'm really wondering is, how would you guys achieve this?
And how would you position each element?

I would like to use this example as a starting point, if that's not impossible to do..
http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Here's my CSS code so far (Sorry, couldn't manage to use a code block)

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    background-image:url(img/Full/BrownPattern.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
#shadow {
    background-image:url(img/Full/BGShadow.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:30px;

}
#header {
    height: 58px;
    background-image:url(img/Full/TopLine.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
#contentBg {
    background-image:url(img/Full/Fridge.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
#footer{
    Height:100px;
    background-color:#666666;
}
```

Just updated the code. Will try to work it out a bit before posting an update.
Okay, the CSS works now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe?

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    background: url('bg.png') repeat-x top; /* here I choose to repeat-x */
}
#shadow {
    background: url('shadow.png') repeat-x top;
}
#header {
    height: 100px;
}
#contentBg {
    background: url('contentbg.png') no-repeat top center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="shadow">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="contentBg">
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is similar to what I've tried. But what about the positioning? Thing is, I want all of the backgrounds to fill the height of the page 100%, minus the footer. Meaning, the footer sticks to the lowest part of the content. 

I'll try to update the code in my first post to explain a little better. :)

Comment: So, using the CSS I'm using, the wrapper fills the height of the page, the shadow div fills the height of the page. But not the contentBG for some reason. Might be because of the positioning?
I haven't specified any positioning for the wrapper div, but the shadow div I had to set positioning to "absolute" for it to fill the height of the page. And it might be because of this that the contentBG doesn't fill the height?